# Как правильно согласовать следующее словосочетание?

Tags: согласование

...а также прошёл необходимые по российскому законодательству ряд обязательных процедур...

или:

...а также прошёл необходимый по российскому законодательству ряд обязательных процедур...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В вашем примере опорным словом является слово "ряд", именно с ним должно быть согласование.

..а также прошёл необходимый по российскому законодательству ряд обязательных процедур...

Comment: Спасибо большое. Просто засомневалась, потому что у Розенталя встречала что-то вроде _"большинство решили"_ (согласование по смыслу), и решила, что здесь может быть что-то подобное.

Comment: Там опорное слово "ряд" "большинство" - подлежащие.

Comment: Только не берите за образец Сержа с его "опорным словом". Это из терминологии учителей РКИ и младшеклассников, которые кубики-квадратики рисуют.  Ряд здесь слово **определяемое**. По поводу Розенталя - надо смотреть конкретику.

Answer (score 4):

...а также прошёл (необходимый) ряд обязательных по российскому законодательству процедур...

Думаю, что здесь "обязательность" процедур следует из законодательства, "ряд" - последовательность фактически проведённых процедур, "необходимый" (без этого слова можно и обойтись) может дополнительно подчёркивать, что без этих процедур нельзя было обойтись - ввиду упомянутых далее *обязательных* требований законодательства. Другой вариант сохранить "необходимость": "... ряд необходимых, обязательных по российскому законодательству процедур..."

Comment: Согласен с вами.

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант здесь невозможен в принципе "необходимые" - это именительный или винительный, а "процедур"  - родительный. Даже непонятно как он вам в голову пришел.

Грамматически верно "ряд, необходимый". Но стилистика все равно ужасная. "необходимый ряд" - косноязычно, а "Необходимый и обязательный" - избыточно.

Если есть возможность, исправьте на ***"... а также прошёл ряд процедур, необходимых по российскому законодательству"***. все вопросы снимает.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Первый вариант не мой - так было у авторов.

Comment: Это, я понял. Извините,  неудачно сформулировал. "вам" - это автору.